# Nestjs this.minioClientService.upload is not a function

Tags: node.js, nestjs, minio

This is my **minio-client.service**:

```
@Injectable()
export class MinioClientService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(MinioClientService.name);
  private readonly defaultBucketName = 'default';

  constructor(private minio: Minio.Client) {}

  async upload(
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    bucketName: string = this.defaultBucketName,
  ) {
   // some code & logic
  }
}
```

I imported the above service in my **admins.service**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AdminsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(AdminsRepository)
    // this line 
    private minioClientService: MinioClientService,
    private adminsRepository: AdminsRepository,
  ) {}

  async update(file) {
    if (file) {
      // error happens here 
      const uploadedImage = await this.minioClientService.upload(file);
      console.log(uploadedImage);
    }
  }
```

And Error Message:
[image]

I also imported **minio-client.module** in **admins.moudle** and there is no error when starting application. The error happens when this **update** method is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `@InjectRepository()` decorator in the wrong spot. That decorator is now telling Nest to inject `AdminsRepository` for the parameter that is supposed to be `MinioClientService`, but this is outside of what Typescript can read. Use this for your constructor instead

```js
  constructor(
    // this line 
    private minioClientService: MinioClientService,
    @InjectRepository(AdminsRepository)
    private adminsRepository: AdminsRepository,
  ) {}
```

And it should work just fine.